# How to use IP address as common name in selfsigned certificate?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, self-signed

I recently generated self signed certificate using OpenSSL with common name as 'localhost' it works fine.

I tried using IP address instead of localhost, which Chrome browser rejected saying `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`, because IP address is not resolved to common name.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Either you have very old Chrome or your Q is inaccurate, because Chrome hasn't accepted _either_ name _or_ address in CommonName for a year. Chrome now requires the SubjAltNames aka SAN extension. **Put (all) your desired name(s) and/or address(es) in SAN**, and optionally one of them in CN for clients other than Chrome. See https://serverfault.com/questions/845766/generating-a-self-signed-cert-with-openssl-that-works-in-chrome-58 and https://serverfault.com/questions/880804/can-not-get-rid-of-neterr-cert-common-name-invalid-error-in-chrome-with-self