# Epson TM-T88V-i SSL Certificate issue

Tags: ssl

I have an Epson TM-T88V-i receipt printer which I print to using Epson's E-pos Javascript library. I have been using the following URL to print to the printer which is connected to my local network

`http://192.168.1.105/cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi?devid=local_printer&timeout=60000`

This has run fine while my application has been unsecured but I have now installed a certificate on my main domain to secure it from a trusted CA and have been facing the issue that when I print to the secure URL for the printer `https://192.168.1.105/cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi?devid=local_printer&timeout=60000` it breaks the security of my main domain -  flagging the site is not secure and crossing the HTTPS in red because it is loading content with certificate errors .

When I inspect the self-signed certificate generated by the printer it has the following issues:

> Certificate - Subject Alternative Name missing The certificate for
>   this site does not contain a Subject Alternative Name extension
>   containing a domain name or IP address.

---

> Certificate - missing This site is missing a valid, trusted
>   certificate (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).

I have tried to add the certificate to my trusted certificate Authorities but this hasn't worked.

I have followed Epson's own guide to create a certificate using OpenSSL but I get the same error in my browser.

I have googled the above errors but just can't find a solution that works. Ignoring all Certificate errors is not an option as this is for a live production environment. I have enabled `Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost` and this too has not worked.

If I need to purchase certificate I will but don't know if A CA can issue one without a signing request

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Chrome requires certs to have SAN, while other browsers still consider it only preferred. This is recent, about a year ago; is the Epson guide newer than that? It's not hard to create certs with SAN using OpenSSL; see my links at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055175/ as a starting point but note SAN differentiates DNS name from IP address; if you are connecting with that address (192.168.1.105) you must use SAN's IP format. A CA will absolutely not issue you a cert for RFC1918 addresses including 192.168/16; doing so would cause a serious security breach.

Comment: Yes, I'm using chrome. I'd prefer not to switch to another browser as they will most likely follow suit so only a matter of time before I have the same problem. I followed this to create a certificate - https://gist.github.com/jchandra74/36d5f8d0e11960dd8f80260801109ab0 and fixed the SAN issue but now I have a Common Name invalid error. What should I put as the common name - I'm using the IP of the printer (192.168.1.105)

Comment: If you are using the address in the URL then yes you should have the address in CommonName, and more importantly in SAN _using IP format not DNS format_ (as I said).

Comment: What does SAN IP format look like?

Answer (score 3):

This was the config that I got to work eventually from following this guide. Thanks to Mark Farrugia for pointing out to change the altNames from DNS.0 to IP.0 - This was what seemed to be the major sticking point for us

https://gist.github.com/jchandra74/36d5f8d0e11960dd8f80260801109ab0

```
#
# epson.cnf
#

[ req ]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = server_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req

[ server_distinguished_name ]
commonName = 192.168.1.105
stateOrProvinceName = mystate
countryName = mycountry
emailAddress = myemail.email.com
organizationName = epson
organizationalUnitName = presales

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
IP.0 = 192.168.1.105 -- this is the IP of the printer
```

It must be noted. I had to download the certificate and add it to Chrome's own trusted CA store on my other PC's. Once added It works as expected

Comment: Following this post I was able to get the administrative website to work with a valid certificate, but the ePOS-Print API isn't working. Are you using the ePOS JavaScript SDK? When I connect to /cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi via HTTP it works. But when I connect to the same url via HTTPS it says page not found.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to sort the issue. Followed your tutorial but then make sure that when you come to the config of the actual certificate add IP.0 to the actual ip of the printer. Now my issue is that it does not connect to the printer using HTTPS through Javascript but a hack in the actual javascript should do it.

Comment: So your browser is recognising the certificate with no issues?

Comment: yes after a lot of swearing yes :)... make sure you specify the IP of the server in the conf file. So underneath you should write the following [ alt_names ] IP.0 = 192.168.1.187
DNS.1 = invoicesmash.local

Comment: Following this post I was able to get the administrative website to work with a valid certificate, but the ePOS-Print API isn't working. Are you using the ePOS JavaScript SDK?  When I connect to /cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi via HTTP it works.  But when I connect to the same url via HTTPS it says page not found.

Answer (score 0):

WHY: this is happen because of epson printer is not generated a valid certificated or untrusted by your PC, so it will block any connection to printer and have this warning like this image
HOW: go to your epson IP, then click process then PC will have printer certificate, then it can connect properly. [image]

Go to this link and make some test:
https://xanhtool.github.io/epbex/

[image]

change this ip with your ip:
[image]

click send and get error:
[image]

open Advance and process:
[image]

send successful:
[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I've got an error "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"