# XHR to non-ssl IP

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I would like to create a Javascript XHR request to a local IP of an Epson TM88V Printer. The site has a SSL certificate so we've to make a secured connection. Unfortunately, it is not possible to upload a certificate in the printer.

Is it possible to add a certificate in the XHR request or is there another way to create a secured connection?

Below the print code without SSL.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://192.168.1.168/cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi?devid=local_printer', true);
xhr.timeout = 5000;
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
         callback({ success: false, data: data });
    } else if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        callback({ success: true, data: data });
        }
    }
xhr.send('<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><epos-print xmlns="http://www.epson-pos.com/schemas/2011/03/epos-print">Test print</epos-print></s:Body></s:Envelope>');
```

Comment: Set up a proxy (running under an https origin) that makes the request in server-side code instead of in your frontend code

Comment: Proxy sounds like a good idea, but it isn't possible to create a server side command to a local printer IP.

Comment: Then seems like you need to SSL-enable the web server running on the printer. The question and answers at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116786/epson-tm-t88v-i-ssl-certificate-issue seem to indicate that’s possible