# Connect Locally Connected Printer from a SSL protected HTTPS React JS Web App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, https, epson, pos

I am working on a web application made in MERN stack and had integrated [Epson Javascript SDK](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_epos_sdk_js_en/index.php?content_id=1) to print receipts as we are using **Epson TM-M30 Printer**. Web app might be running on mostly Safari but it can chrome or firefox sometimes.

I doubt assigning a CA certificate to a private IP will work or not. Correct me if I am wrong.

It works perfectly in `localhost` on `PORT 8008` with respective printer `IPs` and `deviceID` as per they mention in their SDK Document [connection function](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_epos_sdk_js_en/index.php?content_id=3).

When I try to access the same printer using the same web application hosted on Domain that is running on HTTPS protocol on `PORT 8043` which is specifically mentioned in SDK document [connection function](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_epos_sdk_js_en/index.php?content_id=3). Browser blocks web application request to print receipt and throws `ERR_CERTIFICATE_INVALID`.

I had checked in Printer configuration and it shows that printer is running on `SELF SIGNED CERTIFICATE`.

Is there a way to make it accessible?

I am requesting connection using the following piece of code:

```
  new epson.ePOSDevice().connect(ipAddress, port); PORT: 8008 for localhost and 8043 from hosted domain
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem ?

Comment: @JoeAllen, Hard luck, however there is one work around, if user first visits printer's url and then try printing, it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Your options here are a bit limited, either you need to install a signed certificate on the printer or you need to configure your browser to allow self signed certs, which is something that browser makers have made harder over the years.

You don’t say which printer or browser you are using, so it hard to give a full answer, however if your using Chrome you can follow these [instructions](https://www.pico.net/kb/how-do-you-get-chrome-to-accept-a-self-signed-certificate).

Comment: I had already mentioned Printer model also I had added target browsers in question

Comment: Have you seen this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116786/epson-tm-t88v-i-ssl-certificate-issue

Comment: Yes, I do, but If I had to target a single user that might work, but asking every user to add certificates and then configure their browser might not be a good idea. I think I am missing something from the SDK because they provide a separate port 8043 for SSL/TLS connections then what is the use of that port?

Comment: I guess it is for kiosk type settings, where you control every browser. If you want any user to connect to the printer, your only option is to put a signed cert on the printer. I suggest you talk to the manufacturer about how to do that, if they don’t support  you have a problem.

Comment: That said maybe you could create a proxy server between the printer and the network, that way only the proxy would need to except the dodgy cert

Comment: @DavidBradshaw How do you expect any proxy server to intercept calls that are happening inside a LAN network? 

"your only option is to put a signed cert on the printer" If you mean CA signed then he already wrote in the question that printer has private IP

Comment: You set up a reverse proxy to look like a printer on your network and then forward the requests to the real printer.